# Get CannotWriteFileException when upload 120mb file on nginx server

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx, laravel-7

I have a Laravel 7 project on the Ubuntu + Nginx server. I can upload files less than ~10mb, but when i am trying to upload a 120mb file I got an error. I am already changed memory_limit, upload_max_filesize, post_size to 640mb in php.ini. It did not help. I am also restart php-fpm and nginx services.

[image: error looks like]

### ERROR LOG

```
2021/01/21 21:11:51 [warn] 13069#13069: *1 a client request body is 
buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/body/0000000001, client: 92.47.198.158, server: servername, request: "POST /courseclass/17 HTTP/2.0", host: "servername", referrer: "https://servername/courseclass/17"
2021/01/21 21:11:53 [error] 13069#13069: *1 openat() "/var/www/servername/video/class/video_course_1611240590.mp4" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 92.47.198.158, server: servername, request: "GET /video/class/video_course_1611240590.mp4 HTTP/2.0", host: "servername", referrer: "https://servername/watch/course/6"
2021/01/21 21:11:54 [error] 13069#13069: *1 openat() "/var/www/servername/video/class/video_course_1611240590.mp4" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 92.47.198.158, server: servername, request: "GET /video/class/video_course_1611240590.mp4 HTTP/2.0", host: "servername", referrer: "https://servername/watch/course/6"
2021/01/21 21:41:18 [error] 13069#13069: *8 openat() "/var/www/servername/images/light.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 92.47.149.211, server: servername, request: "GET /images/light.jpg HTTP/2.0", host: "servername", referrer: "https://servername/"
2021/01/21 21:41:21 [error] 13069#13069: *8 openat() "/var/www/servername/images/light.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 92.47.149.211, server: servername, request: "GET /images/light.jpg HTTP/2.0", host: "servername", referrer: "https://servername/"

    2021/01/21 21:49:53 [warn] 13069#13069: *10 an upstream response is 
buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/3/00/0000000003 while reading upstream, client: 92.47.198.158, server: servername, request: "POST /courseclass/17 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/servername.sock:", host: "servername", 
referrer: "https://servername/courseclass/17"
```

Comment: Did you restart your php process after you changed the settings so that the new configuration is applied?

Comment: @codedge Yes, I restarted both php-fpm and nginx

Comment: Another idea is to check the `client_max_body_size` setting for nginx. You should also check your logs for php if there are more details in it. They are mostly located ad `/var/log/nginx/*`, mostly defined in your vhost file.

Comment: @codedge client_max_body_size already increase it. Let me check the log files

Comment: @codedge add log content

Comment: The warning shouldn't be limiting factor. Instead of putting the file into the RAM, nginx created a temporary file. But there does not seem to be an error, if you upload the file. Without any more error details, messages, it is hard to tell why it fails

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the less memory of the server. After I increase it from 5GB to 10GB there is no problems. But before that there was about 200MB and I tried to upload a video of 100MB